# Signed Application file - how to get the signature from the file?

Tags: windows, digital-signature, sha1

I am downloading a file that want to install on my computer. I know that it will be Ok to install if the signature matches the signature I have on file for the distributor of that file.

I am not downloading directly from the distributor though so I want to check that the file is signed with their key.

I have downloaded a version of openssl for windows but I can't see from that how to tell what the key is from the application file. I've seen many files for download say that their hash is x but what I am looking for is the distributor's key which from the file itself. What I have to compared it against is the SHA1-40-hex digit key.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the JDK and used it's [jdk]\bin\keytool.exe to run the following:
keytool -list -printcert -jarfile [path_to_your_apk] > signature.txt

If you look through that file you can see the signature section at the top and the required signature in it. Thanks.